# How to use custom code inside multiline strings?

Tags: php, heredoc

I am trying to run PHP code inside DELIMETER but it does not work.

I want to do a box to show all quantity available on my stock.

This is my code:

```
$product = <<<DELIMETER
<a class="btn btn-default">
<select id ="quantidade" name="quantidade"> <?PHP for ($i = 0; $i<=$row['produto_quantidade']; $i++) echo "<option value=".$i.">".$i." </option>";
?>  </select> </a>
DELIMETER;
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: You're already inside PHP, you can't use `<?php` again when you're already in PHP.